# How to sum a manipulated array in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel

In Excel, if I have an array named `x`, I can calculate it's sum using `sum(x)`.

How can I calculate the sum of `x^2`?

Note this question is more about how to use element wise manipulated arrays, I am not looking for an alternative function that takes `x` as an input.

I would like to know how to use `sum()` and x without creating a secondary array `x2=x^2` and using `sum(x2)`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Presume this is referring to arrays in VBA? If so, perhaps add a tag to that effect.

Comment: I don't know VBA, so I was hoping a simple solution existed without using VBA. But I'm willing to learn it if that's the only way to do this. In Matlab, this is really easy. If you have an array called x and you want to sum it's squares, you just type sum(x.^2). I was hoping for an easy solution like this.

Comment: No, it does exist. Just wasn't sure whether you were referring to VBA or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`=SUMPRODUCT(x^2)`

or, **array formula****:

`=SUM(x^2)`

Both require that all entries within *x* be numeric. Otherwise, further manipulation is required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: That's perfect! I did not know about ctl shift in Excel. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, though I might add that if a non-CSE solution exists then it's generally preferable to take it, if for no other reason than the fact that you don't have to remember a certain keystroke combination each time you wish to recommit it!